# Какая разница между window.innerHeight и document.body.offsetHeight?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Чем отличается `window.innerHeight` от `document.body.offsetHeight`?

Comment: В принципе никакая, но `window.innerHeight` - это высота всего окна сайта, а `document.body.offsetHeight` высота `<body />`

Comment: @yuriy, `В принципе никакая,` для данной страницы первая - 598, вторая - 1877. Ни какой разницы не заметил :)

Comment: @Visman, бывает и такое :D

Answer (score 4):

`window.innerHeight` - вернёт высоту окна, а `document.body.offsetHeight` высоту всей страницы